# Spring Boot in Eclipse - no .war created

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I have a `Spring Boot` application running in `Eclipse` and when starting it (code below) I can reach the url and have the app working.

Now I need to generate a `war` file and run the app on a server. I followed the steps [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging) for creating a deployable `war` file and if I understand correctly when building the project `Spring` should create the `war`. But no `war` file is created.

What am I missing?

Here's the code for staring the app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class StreamProjectApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(StreamProjectApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(StreamProjectApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The relevant snippets of the `pom.xml` file:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
...
...

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

EDIT: the full pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.project</groupId>
<artifactId>projectname</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>projectname</name>
<description>projectname</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.27</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Comment: whats generated in the `target` folder after running the commands?

Comment: The `target` has `m2e-wtp` and inside it `web-resources/META-INF`. But no `war` file.

Comment: and the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` is in the POM?

Comment: Yes. `<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>`

Comment: could you post full pom.xml? something could be missing in that.

Comment: How have you called Maven? From inside Eclipse or from plain command line?

Comment: @pro_cheats I added the full `pom.xml` to the question.

Comment: I installed maven and I'm creating the war file using `mvn package` from the command line. It's not the solution I was hoping for but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this plugin to the `build` section

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</plugin>
```